# How do portkeys work?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-transportation

At the start of GoF, the portkey has a time that it is due to leave, and the implication is that it will leave at that time whether there are people touching it or not.

Towards the end of the book however, the portkey is activated by touch and presumably wouldn't have left until it was touched.

Is this a contradiction or are there different spells for this?

Comment: It's, quite literally, magic. Most traditions of magic in stories, or otherwise, assign varying degrees of dependence on the intent of either the user, the maker/caster, or both. From the meta-standpoint of the story, magic does whatever the author needs it to.

Comment: I have removed my answer from here and moved it to the duplicate question [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/155830/68872)